# Matching interval brackets

Tags: filetype-tex, plugin-vimtex

I'm using vim to edit LaTeX code, and I'm often writing intervals like `(a,b]` but this messes with other vim features.  For instance,

- Jumping with <kbd>%</kbd>: if I have something like `\phi((a,b])`, the final `)` will match the second `(` and some closing parenthesis later in the code will match the first.
- There's a feature (I'm not sure if it's specific to vimtex or just a feature of vim) where <kbd>]</kbd><kbd>]</kbd> closes any open delimiters, and this makes that behave wrongly - it'll try to close the `)` from many lines ago.
- The <kbd>tsd</kbd>/<kbd>csd</kbd>/<kbd>dsd</kbd> features of vimtex which toggle/change/delete surrounding delimiters don't work (I think <kbd>csd</kbd> and <kbd>dsd</kbd> are extensions of vim-surround but I'm not sure). In particular, either they select the wrong delimiters or do nothing at all.

Currently I'm putting `)`s in comments to mitigate this. This solves the problem of parentheses later in the file matching wrongly, but matching in the same line doesn't work (and things like `tsd` from vimtex don't work properly).

Is there any better solution, or a standard solution for this kind of problem? Ideally this would deal with `[a,b)` also.

Comment: This is a very difficult problem, actually. It is very hard to know how to match parantheses if the start and end paranthesis is of different type. I remember we had a discussion about this at a vimtex issue once. You could try to search the issue threads and see if you find anything, or you could create a new issue.

Comment: @KarlYngveLervåg I think [this is the relevant issue](https://github.com/lervag/vimtex/issues/592)?

Comment: Yes, that's relevant. although the topic is indentation. The point is still, as mentioned above, that it is inherently very difficult to get this right for unbalanced parantheses.

Comment: A workaround might be to use the `\DeclarePairedDelimiter` command from the mathtools package to then just write like `\leftopenint{a, b}`. I learned about this in this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/118173/how-to-write-ceil-and-floor-in-latex/)

Comment: @Jan I quite like this solution! If you'd like to write it as an answer I'm happy to accept it.

Answer (score 1):

A workaround might be to use the `\DeclarePairedDelimiter` command from the mathtools package to then just write like `\leftopenint{a, b}`. See the accepted answer to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/118173/how-to-write-ceil-and-floor-in-latex/).

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\leftopenint{(}{]}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\rghtopenint{[}{)}

\begin{document}
  \begin{equation*}
   \leftopenint{-\infty, \frac{1}{N} } \cup \rghtopenint*{\frac{1}{N}, \infty}
  \end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

which gives me what is posted below. Note that the `*` makes the delimiters scale.

[image]

**Just noted** the asymmetric appearance of the brackets in the header also breaks syntax highlighting and the commands like *closing of matching environments*. I could fix this with outsourcing these definitions to a separate file and then use `\include`...